# addWeighted in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I came across the function [addWeighted](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html) in OpenCV, where it was mentioned that it:

```
Calculates the weighted sum of two arrays.
```

Does that mean we multiply the pixels in the first array by some weight, and likewise to the second array, and then simply some the relevant pixel values together?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the OpenCV documentation:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html

[image]

You answer is not completely correct (unless your gamma is 0) because you have to sum the gamma value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as it says there in the docs:

> The function `addWeighted` calculates the weighted sum of two arrays
>   as follows:
>
> ```
> dst(I) = saturate(src1(I)*alpha + src2(I)*beta + gamma)
> ```
>
> where `I` is a multi-dimensional index of array elements. In case of
>   multi-channel arrays, each channel is processed independently.
>
> The function can be replaced with a matrix expression:
>
> ```
> dst = src1*alpha + src2*beta + gamma;
> ```

where `saturate` is the [`saturate_cast<>()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/utility_and_system_functions_and_macros.html#saturate-cast) conversion function (which performs saturation as opposed to modular arithmetic that wraps around)

You can always check the source as well:
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp#L2114

The function has multiple execution paths depending on how you build it (what optimizations are available: SSE2, NEON, unrolled version, and then finally a fallback implementation) and the data types involved.